# How to get the indexes and reoccurrences of a specific character?

Tags: c#, string, indexing, character

IF in a string there is a character or characters that occurs again and again. Like in the following string:

```
1+1+1-2+2/2*4-2*3/23
```

Now in the string above the `+` occurs `3` times at the indexes of `1,3,7` and `-` occurs `2` times at the indexes of `5,13` and so others, and then storing them in 2 dimensional array So now the issue is that how to do this.

Comment: How to do what? Find it, count it, replace it?

Comment: Do you want to count the signs or do you need the indexes of them?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't want to replace it, I just want to store it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I want to store the `signs` and there `indexes` in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will return all matched indices for a given search string:

```
List<int> GetAllIndices(string input, string search)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();

    int index = input.IndexOf(search);

    while(index != -1)
    {
        result.Add(index);
        index++;//increment to avoid matching the same index again
        if(index >= input.Length)//check if index is greater than string (causes exception)
            break;
        index = input.IndexOf(search, index);
    }

    return result;
}
```

It should also handle overlapping matches, for example: searching `"iii"` for occurrences of `"ii"` will return `[0,1]`

---

If you want to use this function to create a list of symbols and their indices then I would recommend the following approach:

```
string input = "1+1+1-2+2/2*4-2*3/23";

//create a dictionary to store the results
Dictionary<string, List<int>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

//add results for + symbol
results.Add("+", GetAllIndices(input, "+"));

//add results for - symbol
results.Add("-", GetAllIndices(input, "-"));

//you can then access all indices for a given symbol like so
foreach(int index in results["+"])
{
    //do something with index
}
```

---

You could even go a step further and wrap that in a function that searches for multiple symbols:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetSymbolMatches(string input, params string[] symbols)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<int>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

    foreach(string symbol in symbols)
    {
        results.Add(symbol, GetAllIndices(input, symbol));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Which you can then use like so:

```
string input = "1+1+1-2+2/2*4-2*3/23";

Dictionary<string, List<int>> results = GetSymbolMatches(input, "+", "-", "*", "/");

foreach(int index in results["+"])
{
    //do something with index
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Linq:

```
var allIndices = yourString.Select((c, i) => new { c, i, })
    .Where(a => a.c == '+').Select(a => a.i);
```

To get a dictionary with all characters in the string, for example:

```
var allCharsAllIndices = yourString.Select((c, i) => new { c, i, })
    .GroupBy(a => a.c)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(a => a.i).ToArray());
```

Comment: Brilliant linq, but a standard loop would be faster, if thats what the user is looking for.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Thanks, but how do you know what the user wants?

Answer (score 0):

Simple = best. Without memory allocation.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetIndexOfEvery(string haystack, string needle)
{
  int index;
  int pos = 0;
  string s = haystack;

  while((index = s.IndexOf(needle)) != -1)
  {              
      yield return index + pos;
      pos = pos + index + 1;
      s = haystack.Substring(pos);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with changing 'value'

```
var duplicates = param1.ToCharArray().Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
            .Where(x =>x.item==VALUE).GroupBy(g=>g.index)
             .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key  })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Good and close to what I wrote, but you were earlier! Remarks: `ToCharArray()` is not needed since a `System.String` is already `IEnumerable<char>` in itself, so no need to copy the data to an array there. What does `'CONDITION'` stand for? Did you really mean to group by `g.index`?

Comment: i wrote wrong (and with upper character..shame :/ ) you should write value instead of condition. Like '+' or '5' character

Answer (score 0):

```
string msg = "1+1+1-2+2/2*4-2*3/23";
Dictionary<char, List<int>> list = new Dictionary<char, List<int>>();
for (int i = 0; i < msg.Length; i++)
{
    if (!list.ContainsKey(msg[i]))
    {
        list.Add(msg[i], new List<int>());
        list[msg[i]].Add(i);
    }
    else
        list[msg[i]].Add(i);
}
```

Comment: this will count all instances, not get a list of indices

Comment: Consider using `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey` followed by `list[...]` indexer access (you search for the key again which you just found).